# Group order notation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, notation

I'm working with Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra text, and I encountered some notation that confused me.

The theorem I saw it in reads as follows. Suppose $\varphi:G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism of groups. then ker $ \varphi \unlhd G$ and $G$/ker $\varphi$ $\cong$ $\varphi(G)$.

The corollary to the theorem reads $|G:$ ker $\varphi |=|\varphi(G)|$

What does this latter expression mean? I don't understand how to interpret  $|G:$ ker $\varphi |$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are more familiar with the notation $[G : \ker \phi]$? It means that the index of the subgroup $\ker \phi$ in $G$ is equal to the cardinality of $\phi(G)$, that is, the image of $\phi$.

You can read more on the notion of index of a subgroup [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup). Dummit & Foote introduce the index of a subgroup at page 90 of Chapter 3.

Comment: So it's the same as saying $|$ker$ \varphi|$, but clarifying it's in $G$?

Comment: No, the index of $H$ in $G$ (where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$) is $\dfrac{o(G)}{o(H)}$, or $\dfrac{|G|}{|H|}$ (and this is guaranteed to be integral as the order of a subgroup divides the order of a group).

Comment: So $|G:$ker $\varphi (G)|$ = $|G|/|\varphi (G)|$?, and the point of the theorem is that this is the same as the numbers of fibers of $\varphi (G)$?

Sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: Correct. And every fiber (a coset of $\ker \phi$) has the same cardinality as $\ker \phi$.